# How to create a Arduino/Raspberry pi api?

Tags: php, api, arduino, xmpp, raspberry-pi

I always want to create an API which lets me send value over the internet to an specific Arduino board or raspberry, I know that I can do it with a third party Server like>
https://www.teleduino.org/
or https://www.yaler.net/ or if I use Raspberry I can install it Android and send data through  GCM. But I don't want to use any other server, I already have a PHP hosting.

I think that I need to open a XMPP port or something to call directly the Ethernet shield or the the  raspberry pi IP.

Will I need a static IP.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your best bet is going to be to take advantage of the `WebServer` process [that Adruino provides](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient). The documentation here should give you some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write you own PROTOCOL, it can be based or use other protocol.
If you have complete access to server, my suggestion is to use TCP Socket direcly (Client class on arduino with write e read, like using the Serial), if you can't then you have to "tunnel" your PROTOCOL over an accepted protocol on the server. If it has php then the protocol il HTTP, witch is based on TCP. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session